# What is the US agency to copyright designs made outside US?

Tags: copyright

Is there any website of a United States copyright agency, to protect a design, lets say a cartoon, but for design made outside US?

Comment: You want US Copyright protection or foreign Copyright protection? FYI, the US  has signed international treaties to deal with some of this: http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl100.html

Comment: I was thinking on US copyright, but Ill read a bit more about the subject.

Comment: @Rafael This is old and got very few views...did you figure it out? I'm thinking of putting a bounty on it.

Comment: Oh, I did not followed this up. Do not worry about the bounty, but thanks for remind me this existed.